# Which DI container is using on spring boot with embedded tomcat?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jakarta-ee, inversion-of-control

- a- Tomcat has it's own DI container for Servlets (which are beans).
- b- Spring has it's own bean container (IoC).

When we start spring boot with embedded tomcat, then we have two application-context on runtime?

How can we print/list all application-contexts on a spring application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) feature is provided by Tomcat (but it is in TomEE). There is only one context running, the Spring context.